# resizing divs on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been trying to add a onClick event to the divs which will resize a div to fullscreen when clicking on that div but when I click on a div, all the div are getting expanded. How do I restrict that onClick event to only a single a div and make that single div resize to full screen? I've also added transition so that when it resize to fullscreen, it looks like a animation but all the divs have been affected by it when clicking on just a single div

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.scss";

const colors = [
  "palevioletred",
  "red",
  "green",
  "blue",
  "yellow",
  "orange",
  "lightblue"
];

const randomColor = items => {
  return items[randomHeight(0, items.length)];
};

const randomHeight = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addActiveClass = this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      active: false
    };
  }
  addActiveClass() {
    const currentState = this.state.active;
    this.setState({ active: !currentState });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="container">
        {Array.from({ length: 30 }).map((item, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            style={{
              background: randomColor(colors),
              height: randomHeight(100, 200)
            }}
            className={this.state.active ? "full" : null}
            onClick={this.addActiveClass}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  font: 2em Sansita, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.container > * {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
}

.full{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 2s;
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sound-phu1m?file=/src/styles.scss:0-435)

Comment: all the divs are sharing the same boolean in state

Comment: is there a way through which I can give every div their own onClick handler?

Comment: Have you tried adding the style to `e.target` in the event handler? Like `function(e){e.target.style = style}`

Comment: @nibble no I didn't. how would I go about doing that?

Comment: In your `onClick` event handler, just reference the clicked `div` using `e.target`. `e` is passed as an argument to the handler. Then apply the style. Like:  `addActiveClass(e) {
     e.target.style.color = white; // Add more styles here 
  }`

Comment: but if I resize using your code, I won't be able to bring back to it's normal height and width again after clicking on the div again. I need to toggle between fullscreen and normal size.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/old-bush-gebdn It may help

Comment: @Piyush the problem is that if you comment out the flex direction then it doesn't stay in the masonry layout anymore. also if I click on a tile in your example, it still doesn't take up the full screen and the animation doesn't seem to apply as well

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're sharing one state with all of the divs. In order to resolve this problem, create `activeIndex` state, initialize it with `-1` maybe, and use it like:

```
  // ...

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.addActiveClass = this.addActiveClass.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeIndex: -1
    };
  }
  addActiveClass(activeIndex) {
    this.setState(prev => ({
      activeIndex: prev.activeIndex === activeIndex ? -1 : activeIndex
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {Array.from({ length: 30 }).map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={index}
              style={{
                background: randomColor(colors),
                height: randomHeight(100, 200)
              }}
              className={this.state.activeIndex === index ? "full" : ""}
              onClick={() => this.addActiveClass(index)}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I made some changes but it doesn't seem to work out. can you have a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sound-phu1m?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You've to pass activeIndex in setState. I've edited my answer.

Comment: it's now affecting all the divs in one column instead of affecting  all the divs like it used to

Comment: and i can't seem to toggle back to normal state when i click again

Comment: I've updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-antonelli-o2p2m?file=/src/App.js), class is only applied to 1 element but its the css as well which you need to update.

Comment: i saw your sandbox, the class is applied to all the divs in a certain column. however I want just one div to be fullscreen upon clicking. regarding the toggling, instead of adding " ", i added null and it seems to do the work to bring back to it's normal size

Comment: Actually `full` class is being applied to 1 div only, I've changed `flex-wrap: wrap` to `flex-flow: wrap`. you can check the sandbox again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218417/discussion-between-reactrookie-and-muhammad-ali).